# Angular - Form Validations

Tags: html, angular, angular-forms

I have two forms in my project what i want to do here is if user given input in second form and inputs of all first form or anyone input is empty then i don't want to enable the save button of the second form. and also if input of all second form is empty then also i don't want to enable save button of second form i done something like this

```
<form id="formOne" #formOne="ngForm">
 <!--input tags-->
   <form id="formTwo" #formTwo="ngForm">
     <!--input tags-->
   </form><!-- end of formTow-->
</form><!--- end of formOne-->
```

submit button of second form i done something like this:

```
<button type="button" [disabled]="!formOne.form.valid && !formTwo.form.valid " (click)="saveIt"/>
```

Thank you for help

Comment: Please make understandable sentences ...

Comment: Pls tell me what you not understood? i am not English speaker

Comment: why are you using form inside form

Comment: Well, nothing ...

Comment: Ok i have to 2 forms in my project.if user given some inputs in a second form and in 1 form all inputs are empty or one input is empty then in a second form save button should not be enable.the validation of second form should be depend on first form

Comment: Adesh Kumar i used two form separately but it is not working then i used this all i want that validation of second form should be depend on the first form.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use single form only .if you have scenario than separate and validate them like this.

```
   <form  #formOne="ngForm">
    <!--input tags-->

    </form>

    <form  #formTwo="ngForm">
         <!--input tags-->
    </form>

    <button type="button" [disabled]="!formOne.valid && !formTwo.valid" (click)="saveIt()"/>
```

In Ts :

```
@ViewChild('formOne') formOne: ngForm ;
@ViewChild('formTwo') formTwo: ngForm;

saveIt(){
{
//save form data.
}
```

Comment: Sir problem is that i have save button on both form.save button is not separate from two form sorry sir i not put on this question.

Comment: Than use only one form and put all the controls in that like this:

<form>

..controls

<button type="button" [disabled]="!form.valid" (click)="saveIt()"/>

</form